# Make a java method return different objects in one single call

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I have a java method which has to return both `List<ObjectA>` and a `List<List<String>>` for each and every call made to it.

One way I can think of achieving this is by returning `Map<String, Object>` where string will be key and object will be my lists.
But I think returning a Map is not an elegant way of doing so in my scenario. Any help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java 14+, we have the possibility to use [Records (JEP 395, `openjdk.org`)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395). Without knowing anything of the semantics, I will demonstrate the usage with a generic `record Pair`, but we can of course always find more descriptive names.

We define a generic `Pair` of generic types `T` and `U`:

```
record Pair<T, U> (T first, U second) {}
```

And a dummy-implementation of `ObjectA`:

```
class ObjectA {
  private final String name;

  public ObjectA(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "ObjectA{" +
        "name='" + name + '\'' +
        '}';
  }
}
```

We can then implement our method like this:

```
public static Pair<List<ObjectA>, List<List<String>>> foo() {
  return new Pair<>(
      List.of(new ObjectA("one"), new ObjectA("two")),
      List.of(
          List.of("three", "four"),
          List.of("five", "six"),
          List.of("seven", "eight")));
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var fooResult = foo();
System.out.println(fooResult.first()); // prints the List<ObjectA>
System.out.println(fooResult.second()); // prints the List<List<String>>
System.out.println(fooResult);
```

This would produce the following output:

```
[ObjectA{name='one'}, ObjectA{name='two'}]
[[three, four], [five, six], [seven, eight]]
Pair[first=[ObjectA{name='one'}, ObjectA{name='two'}], second=[[three, four], [five, six], [seven, eight]]]
```

(Sorry, no `Ideone.com` demo, Ideone does not support Java 14+, only Java 12)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's no real universal answer to this question.

One could argue that every time you use `Object` in Java, it's already somewhat bad since you haven't defined a proper `Object` containing all of the stuff you need, on the other hand, I really know how much of an annoyance this can be, therefore I try to stick to data structures already available, mainly `Maps`.

The main problem is that your method(s) calling the method returning an `Object` need to cast the results anyway - without the knowledge of what this function does, it's hard to give any real advice here.

Therefore my approach would be to look at what exactly are we returning and what these objects actually contain.

I guess the even easier way would be to define a `List<List<String>>` on your `ObjectA` and just check of the existence of that list and modify your other method accordingly, if that does make any sense in the context of `ObjectA` and your methods.

Other than that, I'd probably go with a `Map<String,Object>` or even `Map<?,Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly,
you should create a class with two fields `List<ObjectA>` and `List<List<String>>`
as a model class. after filling the object with the required data, return it as a return type.

The model class sample :

```
public class TestModel{
  private ObjectA objectA;
  private List<List<String>> listOfStrings ; 
}
```

Your method will be :

```
public TestModel doSomething(....){

//do something
...

//in the end
TestModel testModel = new TestModel();
testModel.setObjectA(objectA);
testModel.setListOfStrings(listOfStrings);
return testModel;
}
```